# Weak solution to Stochastic differential equations

Tags: stochastic-calculus, stochastic-differential-equations

This is a homework exercise. I am asked to show that the stochastic process $X_t = B_t^2$ with $B_t$ being a standard brownian motion, is a weak solution to

$$
 dX_t = dt + 2\sqrt{|X|}d\tilde{B}, \quad X_0 = 0
$$
Where $\tilde{B}$ is Another standard brownian motion.

My attempt so far has been to try and use the Itô formula to solve the equation as we have trained in class.

My attempt at a solution was to follow a similar schema as when I found a solution to the same SDE  but with $\tilde{B} = B_t, \quad X_0;= x_0 $. The change being that I set $g(t,x) = x^2$ such that $g' = 2x, g'' = 2$ and substitute into the equation 
$$
dg(B_t) = g(0) + g'dB_t (?) + \frac{1}{2}g'' dt
$$

For the other problem this startegy was succesful when choosing $g(t,x) = 2\sqrt{x}$, I was able to follow the literature and derive the correct solution.

Nevertheless I feel very stuck in showing that $X_t = B_t^2$  is indeed a weak solution and need help. How do I show that it is a weak solution?

Comment: Can you edit the question to include your specific attempt?

Comment: @sean-roberson i added more information.

Comment: What is the precise formulation of the problem which you need to solve? As it is currently written, it looks somewhat weird to me.

Comment: The precise formulation reads: let $B_t$ be a standard brownian motion and let $X_t=B_t^2$, show that $X_t$ is a weak solution to the SDE given by $dX_t = dt + 2\sqrt{|X|}d\tilde{B}, \ X_0 =0$ where $\tilde{B}$ is another brownian motion. Precisely as in the OP.